# How can I find a class which inherit from a particular class from my Class list?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I get the list of all classes of my application.

I want to find each Class from my list which inherits from MySpecificWrapperClass.

```
int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
Class *classes = malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
    Class class = classes[i];
    if( isThisClassInheritsFrom(class,MySpecificWrapperClass )){
       MySpecificWrapperClass o = [[class alloc]init];
       ...
    }
} 
free(classes);
```

Dose somebody know how to do that?
Thank for help.
Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but brute force should do it. [class_getSuperclass](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW15) returns the `Class` object for a given `Class` object's superclass. When you get to the root class, it returns `Nil`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
    Class class = classes[i];
    Class superclass = class_getSuperclass(class);
    while( superclass != Nil ){
        if( superclass == MySpecificWrapperClass ){
           // Got one!
           break;
        }
        superclass = class_getSuperclass(superclass);
    };
}
```

This is assuming that you want to check the *entire* hierarchy for a given class, i.e., you want every class that has your class anywhere in its ancestors. If you only care about direct subclasses, obviously, you only need to call `class_getSuperclass` once.

Comment: The hierarchy is basically just a linked list, after all. Glad to help!

Comment: Found it useful too does seem heavy handed though +1 still

Answer (score 0):

To test if a class is inherits of your class, try

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass: MySpecificWrapperClass])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At that level, I do not have an object.Just the class. If I instentiate my class I can do this, but it is not as proper that if I can do whithout.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know of any way to accomplish that without an actual object of the class. Best of luck with that though!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a class is a subclass of another class with the `isSubclassOfClass:` method defined by `NSObject`.

[NSObject class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I did: `for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
  Class class = classes[i];
  NSLog(@"Check %p",class );
  if( [class isSubclassOfClass: [PortWrapper class]]){
   NSLog(@"Find %@",class );
   if( [class isCompatible:[self port]]  ){
    [types addObject:class];
   }
  }
 }` but it crashs in one of classes.