# Dynamically List IBOutlets of a Class

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I've been working with this

```
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([NSString class], &outCount);
```

which has two limitations that I don't know how to resolve:

1. It doesn't list inherited properties.
2. I can't differentiate IBOutlets from other properties.

How can I dynamically list all the IBOutlet properties in a class (or instance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IBOutlet` is [`#define`d as a blank string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/IBOutlet); it doesn't have any effect at either compile or run time. Its sole purpose is to allow Interface Builder to look at header files and see which ivars should be used as connections. The only way for you to determine which ivars were declared as `IBOutlet`s would be to likewise do some text processing of the header file of whatever class you're working with.

For the properties, I'm not sure there's any other way than going up the list of superclasses and getting all their properties too. You can call `class_getSuperclass` in a loop to get the whole ancestry of your class;* the function returns `Nil` when you call it with the root class (`NSObject`) as the argument.

---

*See, e.g., [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013448/how-can-i-find-a-class-which-inherit-from-a-particular-class-from-my-class-list/6035632#6035632) of mine.

Comment: Thanks Josh, that's a great answer (the reality sucks, but the answer is good). What about the other question: inherited properties?

Comment: Updated. Also, now that I think of it, there may be another way to get at the list of outlets than just looking at the text. Interface Builder allows you to add outlets to a class from its GUI, and that doesn't put anything into the header. I haven't really any idea how that works; you could poke around the nib-loading documentation, though.

Comment: Very very cool, many thanks @Josh Caswell. The reason I care about all of this is that I'm trying to avoid NIB loading problems a la http://vgable.com/blog/2008/12/12/one-assert-you-need/ ... that said, most of the problems go the other way around, i.e., the outlet name has changed instead. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

from what I've read this is not possible. The reason is that IBOutlet is a macro that resolves to nothing. So there is nothing in the compiled app to detect. It is used by interface builder which looks at the raw source code where it can see it.